# Printing frequency of word

Tags: java, string

I have written a piece of code to print the frequency of words in a String but if I input multiple spaces, I am getting count of spaces in the output.

```
//import the necessary packages if needed
import java.util.*;   
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")//Do not delete this line
public class CountOfWords
{
         public static void main (String[] args) {
             Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

             System.out.println("Enter Student's Article");
             StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(sc.nextLine());

             String str=sb.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[,;:.?!]","");

             List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));

             System.out.println("Number of words "+list.size());

              SortedSet<String> uniqueWords = new TreeSet<String>(list);
             System.out.println("Words with the count");

              for(String s:uniqueWords)
              {
                  int freq=Collections.frequency(list,s);
                  System.out.println(s+": "+freq);
              }

         }
}
```

Running the program:

```
Enter Student's Article
hello Hello HEllo hi hi: hi! Welcome,   welcome                                                         
Number of words 10                                                              
Words with the count                                                            
: 2                                                                             
hello: 3                                                                        
hi: 3                                                                           
welcome: 2
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to detect multiple spaces

```
str.trim().split("\\s+");
```

You need to call `trim` method before splitting by tokens. Otherwise, the output of "   Stack Over Flow" (one space at the beginning of the sentence) can be `[" ", "Stack", "Over", "Flow"]`

Answer (score 1):

Replace the for loop by this one:

```
for(String s : uniqueWords){
   if (!s.equals(" ")) {
      int freq = Collections.frequency(list, s);
      System.out.println(s + ": " + freq);
   }
}
```

Here only the strings that are not equal to " " are printed in your output.

Comment: For string comparison use `String#equals()`

Comment: It would work but it’s not the cleanest solution as OP can trim its string as answered below :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex for splitting:

`List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+"));`

Here could be a reference: 
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-split-string-in-java-by-whitespace-or-tabs.html

For your original approach of simply putting a space, i.e. " ", to the split() method, it would stop processing the subsequent space while it has encountered the first occurrence; which leads to the expected result you have encountered.